# Wireguard config to access local network hosts/whole internet

Tags: vpn, wireguard

I'm having trouble with what I think is a simple Wireguard setup.
Goals:

- access local network hosts from my Android device (I don't want to forward all traffic).
- forward all traffic through the VPN server from my Macbook

Setup:

- router at 10.0.0.1
- Intel NUC at 10.0.0.2 (running WG)
- other hosts at 10.0.0.x
- an Android device
- a Macbook

NUC config:

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = REDACTED
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

# android
[Peer]
PublicKey = p2q9PYui5MeYzUzKxGUXHjN77sOTYUsZQmdjEsbhxBs=
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.2/32

#[Peer]
# macbook config, TODO
```

Android config

```
Interface Addresses is set to 192.168.0.2/24
Peer Allowed IPs is set to 0.0.0.0/0 (temporarily, I'd like to limit it to local LAN hosts once everything is working)
Peer Endpoint: my-endpoint.com:51820
```

With this configuration, the Android device can connect just fine, but only sees 10.0.0.2 (the NUC). The internet and all other local hosts are unreachable.

I tried many different combination but can't figure it out.